# jQuery 1.8.3 xsrf error after close the browser

Tags: jquery, tornado

I just found a strange problem,  I use tornado to run my site and in tornado POST need _xsrf parameter, the following code worked fine when I use jQuery version 1.7.2, but I get POST 403 error when I reopen the browser (keep cookie alive) after I change jQuery to version 1.8.3... But 1.7.2 and before just works fine...

403 in tornado means the _xsrf is not correct.
The point is that the 403 error happens when I reopen the browser, I still loginin but can't POST.

Anyone know the problem ? following is the code

```
        function getCookie(name) {
                var r = document.cookie.match("\\b" + name + "=([^;]*)\\b");
                return r ? r[1] : undefined;
        }

        jQuery.postJSON = function(url, args, callback) {
                    args._xsrf = getCookie("_xsrf");
                    $.ajax({
                                url: url, data: $.param(args), dataType: "text", type: "POST", async: true,
                                success: function(response) {
                                    if (callback) callback(eval("(" + response + ")"));
                                }, 
                                error: function(response) {
                                    try{
                                        args._xsrf = getCookie("_xsrf");
                                        $.ajax({url: url, data: $.param(args), dataType: "text", type: "POST", async: true,
                                            success: function(response) {
                                                if (callback) callback(eval("(" + response + ")"));
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                    catch(e){

                                    }
                                }
                    });
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem. For some reason, '_xsrf' value is deleted from cookie after browser restart. The question is, why tornado doesn't set this cookie again? Looking in tornado code (web.py):

```
    token = (self.get_argument("_xsrf", None) or
             self.request.headers.get("X-Xsrftoken") or
             self.request.headers.get("X-Csrftoken"))
    if not token:
        raise HTTPError(403, "'_xsrf' argument missing from POST")
    if self.xsrf_token != token:
        raise HTTPError(403, "XSRF cookie does not match POST argument")
```

we can see, that if _xsrf is not found anywhere in request, then request immediately rejected. New cookie values will be set at line

```
    if self.xsrf_token != token:
```

That is not reached (self.xsrf_token is a function, that is wrapped with @property).

So, the simpliest workaround is:

1. Change function getCookie to return some string in case of _xsrf not found in cookie. For example 'not_found':

   ```
   function getCookie(name) {
       var r = document.cookie.match("\\b" + name + "=([^;]*)\\b");
       if (!r && name == "_xsrf"){
           return 'not_found'
       }
       return r ? r[1] : undefined;
   }
   ```
2. Now, after first bad request, tornado will set _xsrf cookie. And second request shall pass

Another solution:

Every time you render a page in tornado, hit property `self.xsrf_token` in you request handler. So you'll be sure, that '_xsrf' cookie is set.

Comment: is there a disadvantage to not executing `self.xsrf_token` on every request in `self.prepare()`?